# measuring distance from points to a line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, distance

I have a couple of points and a line in an RGB image. I want to measure the shortest distance from the points to the line. What do you suggest for these distance measurements?

edited

[image]

I am using python and OpenCV.
The line has a width which is 10cm.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) out

Comment: Do you mean you want to know which one of the 4 red blobs is nearest the line? Or do you mean you want to know for each of the 4 red blobs, which pixel within that blob is nearest to the line? Or are your red blobs poor representations of your image and you actually just have a single pixel where you have drawn 20-30 pixels? Do you actually have the equation of the line and want to know the mathematical formula for the distance between a point and a line? In general are you interested in the centroid of each point, or all the pixels making up the blob?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, what I mean is that I want to measure the distance from each of these points to the line. I know the equation of the line and the position of the dots."In general are you interested in the centroid of each point, or all the pixels making up the blob?" this does not matter. What I really want is the perpendicular distance between dots and the line.

Comment: You have the equation for the line, so please show it. You know the coordinates of each of the red dots, so please show them. The equation to determine the shortest distance is here... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line So, I'm not sure which bit you need help with?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I edited it. In fact, the line has a width and I assume it 10cm. The equation is for the right side of the line. I do not know how to write a code to do find the distance. My question is about coding this in python. I understand the math behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Your line has the equation:

```
y = 0.612x + 201.624
```

The [Wikipedia formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) uses the format `ax + by +c =0`, so we re-cast to:

```
-0.612x + y -201.624 = 0
```

Hence:

```
a = -0.612
b = 1
c = -201.624
```

So, if you want to find the distance from point (40,250), you need to plug

```
x0 = 40
y0 = 250
```

into their formula:

[image]

So, the distance you seek (in pixels) is:

```
abs(-0.612 * 40 + 250 -201.624) / sqrt(-0.612 * -0.612 + 1*1)
```

You will then need to scale that by the relationship between pixels and real-world.